# Tableau suppress null heat map elements

Tags: tableau-api

I built a heat map chart to display the number of properties (`Count of APN`) on street and the year that they were built:

[image]

Unfortunately, the heat map displays a dot for street/year combinations where the `Count of APN` is null:

[image]

** edit 0 **

- `Year Built` is defined as a `Number (whole)`.
- `Age` is a calculation, defined as a `Number (whole), based on`Year Built`
- `Age (bin)` and `Year Built (bin)` are based on their respective fields

Null values aren't displayed when `Age (bin)` is used instead of `Year Built (bin)`:

[image]

** edit 1 **

Followed these steps, as suggested by @semicolon`s answer:

1. Added `Count of APN` to Color:

[image]

2. Edited the color settings:

[image]

3. Changed the palette and range:

[image]

4. No change to viz:

[image]

Is there a way to suppress the dots that represent null values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `bin` feature, I created a calculated field based on the `Year Built` field:

```
Floor([Year Built]/10)*10
```

which resulted in the desired behavior:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use *Color* to suppress the dots in NULL area. Just add the `Count of APN` in *Color* and go to *Edit Colors* in color palette set Palette to *Custom Sequential* and under *Advanced* section set *Start:* as 0.